# Display total count of students

Tags: sql, logic

Display total count of students enrolled in all subjects and helping material is

```
student (rollNumber, Sfname, Slname, email,phone)
Subjects(Subid, subTitle, credit_hrs)
std_sub(rollNUmber (fk from student), subid(fk frim subjects), session, sectionID)
```

and I wrote query

```
select subTitle,Subid,rollNumber,rollNUmber 
from student s 
join std_sub st on s.rollNumber=st.rollNUmber 
join subjects sub on sub.subid=st.subid
```

But it still needs modification

Comment: Have you tried to use count aggregate function? Some samples https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get you correctly then you want to find out `total_students` per subject.

`Count()` which will display number of students enrolled in each subject and any subject has no students then it will show 0 as student count

```
select 
    subTitle,
    Subid,
    coalesce(count(st.rollNumber), 0) as total_students

from subjects sub 

left join std_sub st 
on sub.subid = st.subid 

left join student s
on st.rollNumber = s.rollNUmber

group by 
    subTitle,
    Subid
```

Students with no enrollment

```
select
    rollNumber,
    Sfname,
    Slname
from student
where rollNumber not in (
    select
        distinct rollNumber
    from std_sub
)
```

Comment: @milan muhammad if this solutiont works for you then please click on the tick mark to accept this answer.

Comment: what if when we display student with who is not enrolled in any subject?

Comment: @milan muhammad I have updated the answer.